# disabling preemption while executing schedule() function

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, preemption, cfs

The scheduler entry in Linux starts with executing `schedule()` which then calls the `__schedule()` function. It is defined as :

```
asmlinkage __visible void __sched schedule(void)
{
    struct task_struct *tsk = current;

    sched_submit_work(tsk);
    do {
        preempt_disable();
        __schedule(false);
        sched_preempt_enable_no_resched();
    } while (need_resched());
}
```

My question is - why is there a need to disable preemption in the scheduler code when no other task could possibly call the `schedule()` function and thus preemption should be automatically disabled until the next task is scheduled. Am I missing something basic here?

Comment: "... when no other task could possibly call the `schedule()` function" - Eh? Tasks are allowed to call `schedule()` whenever they want, and they actually do that in [many places](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.8/C/ident/schedule). In any case, the function [__shedule()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.8/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L4001) calls `smp_processor_id()`, which in turn is allowed to be called only with disabled preemption.

Comment: If schedule() is currently executing, how could another task run on the same processor which may call schedule(), unless schedule() itself preempts to another task to run?

Comment: "how could another task run on the same processor which may call schedule(), unless schedule() itself preempts to another task to run?" - You have  just answered your question by yourself: Without disabled preemption the current task could be preempted by some other one on a given CPU.